# Stack Gotoxy Object Oriented

Tags: c++, windows, class, oop

i cant compile with gotoxy, its show me windows.h as an error, its an stack thats show, enter a number, delete top and shohw top, but gotoxy isnt work.

**stack.h**

```
#ifndef STACK_H_INCLUDED
#define STACK_H_INCLUDED

#include <exception>
#include<string>

class StackException: public std::exception
{
private:
    std::string msg;
public:
    explicit StackException(const char* message) :
            msg(message)
    {
    }
    explicit StackException(const std::string& message) :
            msg(message)
    {
    }
    virtual ~StackException() throw ()
    {
    }
    virtual const char* what() const throw ()
    {
        return msg.c_str();
    }
};

///DEFINITION
template<class T, int ARRAYSIZE = 1024>
class Stack
{
private:
    T data[ARRAYSIZE];
    int top;

    void copyAll(const Stack<T, ARRAYSIZE>&);

public:
    Stack(); ///constructor base
    Stack(const Stack<T, ARRAYSIZE>&); ///constructor copy
    void initialize();

    bool isEmpty();
    bool isFull();

    void push(const T&);
    void showStack();

    T pop();

    T getTop();
    void gotoxy(int, int);

    Stack<T, ARRAYSIZE>& operator =(const Stack<T, ARRAYSIZE>&); ///OPERATOR ASIGNED
};

///IMPLEMENTATION
using namespace std;

template<class T, int ARRAYSIZE>
Stack<T, ARRAYSIZE>::Stack() :
        top(-1)
{
}

template<class T, int ARRAYSIZE>
void Stack<T, ARRAYSIZE>::copyAll(const Stack<T, ARRAYSIZE>& s)
{
    int i(0);
    while (i <= s.top)
    {
        this->data[i] = s.data[i];
        i++;
    }
    this->top = s.top;
}
template<class T, int ARRAYSIZE>
Stack<T, ARRAYSIZE>::Stack(const Stack<T, ARRAYSIZE>& s)
{
    copyAll(s);
}

template<class T, int ARRAYSIZE>
bool Stack<T, ARRAYSIZE>::isEmpty()
{
    return top == -1;
}

template<class T, int ARRAYSIZE>
bool Stack<T, ARRAYSIZE>::isFull()
{
    return top == ARRAYSIZE - 1;
}

template<class T, int ARRAYSIZE>
void Stack<T, ARRAYSIZE>::push(const T& e)
{
    if (isFull())
    {
        throw StackException("DATA OVERLOAD, PUSH");
    }
    data[++top] = e;
}

template<class T, int ARRAYSIZE>
T Stack<T, ARRAYSIZE>::pop()
{
    if (isEmpty())
    {
        throw StackException("DATA INSUFFICIENCY, POP");
    }
    return data[top--];
}

template<class T, int ARRAYSIZE>
T Stack<T, ARRAYSIZE>::getTop()
{
    if (isEmpty())
    {
        throw StackException("DATA INSUFFICIENCY, getTop");
    }
    return data[top];
}

template<class T, int ARRAYSIZE> ///& reference
Stack<T, ARRAYSIZE>& Stack<T, ARRAYSIZE>::operator =(const Stack<T, ARRAYSIZE>& s)
{
    copyAll(s);

    return *this;
}

template<class T, int ARRAYSIZE>
void Stack<T, ARRAYSIZE>::showStack()
{
    int ayuda, i;
    if (!isEmpty())
    {
        system("cls");
        printf("\n\n\t\t%c%c%c%c%c  \n", 201, 205, 205, 205, 187);
        for (i = top; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            printf("\t\t%c%c ", 186, 205);
            cout << data[i];
            printf(" %c\n", 186);
            printf("\t\t%c%c%c%c%c\n", 204, 205, 205, 205, 185);

        }
        //system("pause");
    }
}

template<class T, int ARRAYSIZE>
void Stack<T, ARRAYSIZE>::gotoxy(int x, int y)
{
    HANDLE hcon;
    hcon = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    COORD dwPos;
    dwPos.X = x;
    dwPos.Y = y;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hcon, dwPos);
}

#endif // STACK_H_INCLUDED
```

*The problem its with windows.h and gotoxy function*

**mainStack.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string.h>

#include "stack.h"

using namespace std;

bool esNumeric(string);

int main()
{
    Stack<string,10> myStack;
    int opt,number;
    bool repeat = true;
    string line_;

        do{
            do{
                system("cls");
                myStack.showStack();
                cout<<"\n\n---STACK---";
                cout<<"\n 1) ENTER NUMBER\n 2) DELETE TOP\n 3) SHOW TOP \n 4) EXIT"<<endl;
                cout<<"\tOPTION: ";
                getline(cin,line_);
                if (esNumeric(line_)) {
                    repeat = false;
                }
            } while(repeat);
            opt = atoi(line_.c_str());
            switch(opt){
                case 1:{
                        do {
                            system("cls");
                            cout<<"ENTER NUMBER: ";
                            getline(cin,line_);
                            if (esNumeric(line_)) {
                                    if(myStack.isFull()){
                                        cout<<"\nIT IS FULL"<<endl<<endl;
                                    }
                                    else{
                                         myStack.push(line_);
                                    }
                                repeat = false;
                            }
                        } while (repeat);
                        system("pause");
                        system("cls");
                        break;
                }

                case 2:{
                        if(myStack.isEmpty()){
                            cout<<"\nEMPTY STACK"<<endl<<endl;
                        }
                        else{
                            myStack.pop();
                        }
                        system("pause");
                        system("cls");
                        break;
                }
                case 3:{
                        system("cls");
                        if(myStack.isEmpty()){
                            cout<<"EMPTY STACK";
                        }
                        else{
                        cout<<"\nTOP: "<< myStack.getTop()<<endl;
                        }
                        system("pause");
                        break;
                }
                case 4:{
                    cout<<" ";
                    break;
                }
                default:{
                    cout<<"\nOUT OF RANGE."<<endl;
                    system("pause");
                    system("cls");
                }
            }
        }while(opt!=4);
        cout<<"\n\nEND OF THE PROGRAMF\n";
        system("pause");
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

bool esNumeric(string line_)
{
   bool b = true;
   int length = line_.size();

   if (length == 0) { // When user push ENTER
      b = false;
   } else if (length == 1 && !isdigit(line_[0])) {
      b = false;
   } else {
      int i;
      if (line_[0] == '+' || line_[0] == '-')
         i = 1;
      else
         i = 0;

      while (i < length) {
         if (!isdigit(line_[i])) {
            b = false;
            break;
         }
         i++;
      }
   }

   return b;
}
```

**OUTPUT ERROR:**

> In file included from main.cpp:8: ./stack.h:132:7: error: unknown type
>   name 'HANDLE' HANDLE hcon; ./stack.h:133:27: error: use of
>         ^
>   undeclared identifier 'STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE'hcon =
>                                            ^
>   GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE); ./stack.h:134:7: error: unknown
>   type name 'COORD' COORD dwPos; 3 errors generated.
>                     ^

https://repl.it/@ZayxHex/Stack-Validation-Gotoxy-Object-Oriented

Comment: Your example should compile, but I STRONGLY recommend making stack.h complete by including all of the headers that it requires. Don't force header users to include stack.h in any particular special order. That always ends in tears.

Comment: By the way, I'm not clicking that link. Crom only knows what's hiding at the other end.

Comment: Looks like you are missing `#include <windows.h>` in stack.h (or include it before including stack.h).